# @executable_path not working

Tags: c++, macos, linker, dynamic-library

I have installed SDL2. I can link my program with

```
clang++ -lSDL2 -lv8 main.o test.o -o nano8
```

However, for distributing reasons, I'd like to give SDL2 away with the binary, and hence i've copied libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib under /myapp/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
As for the documentation, @executable_path should allow me to link to that dylib instead of the one in /usr/local/lib, but if I run

```
clang++ @executable_path/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib -lv8 main.o test.o -o nano8
```

I get the error

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '@executable_path/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib'
```

How to set the search path for a dylib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pain to get right.

I assume that `/myapp` can be anywhere in the filesystem, and want to load the library from `@executable_path/../lib/libSDL2.dylib`?

If so you have to use the *Run Path* and copy and modify the library during linking (this needs to be done every build):

1. `cp /usr/local/lib/libSDL2.dylib build_dir/lib`.
2. Change the *install name* of the `.dylib` using `install_name_tool`:

   ```
   install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/libSDL2.dylib @rpath/libSDL2.dylib build_dir/lib/libSDL2.dylib
   ```
3. Link against `build_dir/lib/libSDL2.dylib` and set the `rpath` during linking:

   ```
   cd build_dir/bin
   clang++ obj_dir/main.o obj_dir/test.o -o nano8 -L ../lib -lv8 -lSDL2 -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker "@executable_path/../lib"
   ```

I have not tested this and there is likely to be errors.  Use `otool -L` to examine the library references in both the binary and the libraries in order to home-in on this issue.

A cleaner way:

Install your binaries into `/usr/local/bin` and provide any `.dylib`s to be installed into `/usr/local/lib`.  This is better as `/usr/local` is the place for user-binaries and you don't need the faff above.